# getSimple CMS помощь в переименовании подписей в админ панели

Tags: php, html

Подскажите как переименовать вкладки в админ панели?

Код:

```
<?php
/**
 * Navigation Include Template
 *
 * @package GetSimple
 */

$debugInfoUrl = 'http://get-simple.info/docs/debugging';

if (cookie_check()) {
    echo '<ul id="pill"><li class="leftnav"><a href="logout.php" accesskey="'. find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_LOGOUT')).'" >'.i18n_r('TAB_LOGOUT').'</a></li>';
    if (isDebug()) {
        echo '<li class="debug"><a href="'.$debugInfoUrl.'" target="_blank">'.i18n_r('DEBUG_MODE').'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '<li class="rightnav" ><a href="settings.php#profile">'.i18n_r('WELCOME').' <strong>'.$USR.'</strong>!</a></li></ul>';
}

//determine page type if plugin is being shown
if (get_filename_id() == 'load') {
    $plugin_class = $plugin_info[$plugin_id]['page_type'];
} else {
    $plugin_class = '';
}

?>
<h1 id="sitename"><a href="<?php echo $SITEURL; ?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo cl($SITENAME); ?></a></h1>
<ul class="nav <?php echo $plugin_class; ?>">
    <li id="nav_pages" ><a class="pages" href="pages.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_PAGES'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_PAGES');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_upload" ><a class="files" href="upload.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_FILES'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_FILES');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_theme" ><a class="theme" href="theme.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_THEME'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_THEME');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_backups" ><a class="backups" href="backups.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_BACKUPS'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_BACKUPS');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_plugins" ><a class="plugins" href="plugins.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('PLUGINS_NAV'));?>" ><?php i18n('PLUGINS_NAV');?></a></li>

    <?php exec_action('nav-tab');   ?>

    <li id="nav_loaderimg" ><img class="toggle" id="loader" src="template/images/ajax.gif" alt="" /></li>
    <li class="rightnav" ><a class="settings first" href="settings.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_SETTINGS'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_SETTINGS');?></a></li>
    <li class="rightnav" ><a class="support last" href="support.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_SUPPORT'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_SUPPORT');?></a></li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">




    <?php include('template/error_checking.php'); ?>
```

Как правильно изменить:

```
<li id="nav_pages" ><a class="pages" href="pages.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_PAGES'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_PAGES');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_upload" ><a class="files" href="upload.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_FILES'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_FILES');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_theme" ><a class="theme" href="theme.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_THEME'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_THEME');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_backups" ><a class="backups" href="backups.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('TAB_BACKUPS'));?>" ><?php i18n('TAB_BACKUPS');?></a></li>
    <li id="nav_plugins" ><a class="plugins" href="plugins.php" accesskey="<?php echo find_accesskey(i18n_r('PLUGINS_NAV'));?>" ><?php i18n('PLUGINS_NAV');?></a></li>
```

Чтоб изменить подписи {TAB_PAGES}, {TAB_PAGES}, {TAB_FALES}, {TAB_THEME}, {TAB_PAGES}, {TAB_BACKUP}, {PLUGINS_NAV} - и не было фигурных скобок?

[image: scr_1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте не в шаблоне, а в файлах локализации admin/lang

```
    /* 
 * For: include-nav.php
*/
"WELCOME"                       =>  "Welcome", // used as 'Welcome USERNAME!'
"TAB_PAGES"                 =>  "<em>P</em>ages",
"TAB_FILES"                 =>  "F<em>i</em>les",
"TAB_THEME"                 =>  "<em>T</em>heme",
"TAB_BACKUPS"               =>  "<em>B</em>ackups",
"PLUGINS_NAV"           =>  "Plu<em>g</em>ins",
"TAB_SETTINGS"          =>  "<em>S</em>ettings",
"TAB_SUPPORT"               =>  "Supp<em>o</em>rt",
"TAB_LOGOUT"                =>  "<em>L</em>ogout",
```